# kotlin alias property delegation throws Exception

Tags: reflection, properties, delegates, kotlin

i want to add aliases property to some class in kotlin which just delegate themselves to some existed properties

then i invent a method called alias to do so, which unfortunately results in an Exception

```
val <T> Array<T>.length by alias(Array<T>::size)

val <T> Collection<T>.length by alias(Collection<T>::size)

fun <R, T> alias(alias: KProperty1<R, T>) = object : ReadOnlyProperty<R, T> {
    override operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return alias.get(thisRef)
    }
}
```

following the exception stack

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: [Ljava.lang.Object;.getSize()I
at kt.ruby.ArrayKt$length$2.get(Array.kt:34)
at kt.ruby.ArrayKt$alias$1.getValue(Array.kt:40)
at kt.ruby.ArrayKt.getLength(Array.kt)
```

Comment: Note that the exception is thrown only for `Array<T>.length` and not for `Collection<T>.length`.

Comment: @nhaarman nice hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. The following program crashes as well:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a: KProperty1<Array<String>, Int> = Array<String>::size
    a.get(args)
}
```

The problem here is that the generated `KProperty1<Array<String>>` references `getSize()` instead of `length` on `Object[]`.

```
final class MainKt$main$a$1 extends PropertyReference1 {
   public static final KProperty1 INSTANCE = new MainKt$main$a$1();

   public String getName() {
      return "size";
   }

   public String getSignature() {
      return "getSize()I";
   }

   public KDeclarationContainer getOwner() {
      return Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(Object[].class);
   }

   @Nullable
   public Object get(@Nullable Object receiver) {
      return Integer.valueOf(((String[])receiver).getSize());
   }
}
```

See [KT-15618](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15618) for this.